# confusion for view's and viewmodel's responsibility in mvvm architecture

Tags: android, mvvm, architecture, viewmodel

i asked this some days ago [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/405042/confusion-for-views-and-viewmodels-responsibility-in-mvvm-architecture-in-andr) but didn't get any answer

i have a confusion about what code should be placed in view and what in viewmodel

for example click events

here is a snippet code of google ToDo app example for showing application architecture ([Link](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/usecases/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/tasks/TasksFragment.kt)):

```
//this code is placed in view (TasksFragment)
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) =
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.menu_clear -> {
                viewModel.clearCompletedTasks()
                true
            }
            R.id.menu_filter -> {
                showFilteringPopUpMenu()
                true
            }
            R.id.menu_refresh -> {
                viewModel.loadTasks(true)
                true
            }
            else -> false
        }

private fun showFilteringPopUpMenu() {
    val view = activity?.findViewById<View>(R.id.menu_filter) ?: return
    PopupMenu(requireContext(), view).run {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.filter_tasks, menu)

    setOnMenuItemClickListener {
        viewModel.setFiltering(
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.active -> TasksFilterType.ACTIVE_TASKS
                R.id.completed -> TasksFilterType.COMPLETED_TASKS
                else -> TasksFilterType.ALL_TASKS
            }
        )
        viewModel.loadTasks(false)
        true
    }
    show()
  }
}
```

as you can see there are 3 three items for a menu

2 of them delegated to viewmodel and one handled in view

beside that there are some logic in view that make decision based on view's id, but in mvvm definition said there must be no condition in view

Answer (score 1):

Is really easy. It depends, every architecture question is not written in golden characters. But there are some best practices that should be followed. You want to maintain your classes short, readable and most important testable. Moving your business logic to the view model is really important, because then you can test your viewModel with Junit tests without mocking specific Android components.

The `when` you mention is in some way business logic but the `it.itemId` you see is really dependent by the view  and is under the scope of the `run` command, moving into the viewmodel as parameter of the function `setFiltering` would be opinable for few developers

Even advanced Clean Architecture models could have and they actually have the status that is showed with a when, for instance

```
 private fun handleDataState(resource: Resource<List<ProjectView>>) {
        when (resource.status) {
            ResourceState.SUCCESS -> {
                progress.visibility = View.GONE
                recycler_projects.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                resource.data?.let {
                    adapter.projects = it.map { mapper.mapToView(it) }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
            ResourceState.LOADING -> {
                progress.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                recycler_projects.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT

the first  function `viewModel.clearCompletedTasks()`is delegated to the view model because you are going to clear the cache in (usually)a [repository](https://deviq.com/repository-pattern/) layer, in other words you are eliciting what is called an use case, delegating this so called business logic outside the view that is popular today to make it "as dumb as possible", you do not want that the view clear the tasks, but want that the underlyer object that represents the tasks is cleared, and only then is showed in the view as status.

The same is for the third `viewModel.loadTasks(false)` this is an [use case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use_case) as well and furthermore you are also passing a boolean, that is going to be injected into the viewModel, or even beyond if you use clear architecture. The rule of thumb is  the view should have view components, the business logic should stay in the view model. This is a good starting point, but please be aware that the MVVM can be applied to other types of more complex architectures.

Comment: and what about the first function, why two of  them delegated to viewmodel and one handled in view??? is that because as you said it depend on view so it should be handled in view??? is that okey???

Comment: @hamid_c I explained now this in the edit, in the case you are going to accept my reply. Hope is clearer the situation. Architecture needs time to get acquainted to, and there are not golden rules as far the code is "decoupled"

Comment: thanks, now it is more clear, but still have question. consider this: `R.id.menu_filter -> {
                showFilteringPopUpMenu()
                true
            }` in first method, it shouldn't be call viewmodel and then viewmodel decide and notify view to call `showFilteringPopUpMenu()` instead of view to directly call it???

Comment: i mean here that view itself decided to do what (here is showing menu) without allowing viewmodel to decide it and then ask view to do it

Comment: at usually triggers commands, and this happehamid_c, stack overflow is for one question per time:) so if you think I replied to your question please do not hesitate also to accept my response.The point you are asking is quite complex and is related to the use of the dependency injection in architecture.For instance the user is often the o ne that interact through the view. For instance he could press a button, or an item from the menu, and so the app expect a change of state, this happens usually from the view to the viewModel, in an MVVM basic architecture. Hope this helps further:)